# delay the div panel on the bottom

Tags: jquery, css

Hi have a little problem, 
I have a small div panel on very bottom,when I click the button its come out. 
its working fine till over here.

now the problem is, there is a form on this div panel.
when i click the submit button, it div return back to default position.
how I can fix the div for particluar time.

thanks

Comment: use firebug to detect the changes of the style for that div!

Answer (score 1):

You can on submit send some hidden input fields which indicates the position of div, whenever this values are set you should place the div at given coordinates otherwise do it default.

Comment: yes, I am trying to do this through jquery

 $(".button").click(function() {
  $('.panel').css({bottom:'0px'}); 
 }); 
but still its not working

Comment: Because when you submit the form, the page will reload, and the value will get reset to it's original value, you'll need something extra to get it to maintain it's up/down value.

Comment: As I said put inside the form hidden fields and update them with needed value so you can reuse them after form submitted.